# Tool for limiting the maximum loudness

Tags: windows, gratis, music, audio

I am looking for a tool which limits the maximum loudness* of *all* applications to a custom value. It should ideally clamp the loudness to the specified value or – if such a feature is not available – just cut it off.

**Required features**

- Windows (8.1 Pro 64-bit to be precise)
- Adjustable maximum loudness value (e.g. via manual calibration)
- Catches all sounds from the whole system
- Clamps the sounds or just cut it off

**Nice to have**

- Notifications when the sounds exceed the set limit
- Multiple profiles, e.g. one for speakers and one for a headset

<sub>* loudness = dB level emitted by the playback device.</sub>

Comment: Are you looking for Loudness Equalization Software?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes. One practical usage is to prevent my speakers from playing too loud sound just because some software has been misconfigured (by me).

Comment: @ComFreek Than Windows has an inbuilt Volume Normalization option, go to Control Panel (Category View) -> Hardware & Sound -> Sound -> Play Back Tab -> Double Click on the Speaker icon -> Enhancements tab -> Last option... if this suffice than I can post this as an answer, I am not posting as am not sure whether this would suffice your requirement or not

Comment: @Mr.Alien The last option on my PC is "Automatic volume control" (translated; I've got a German Windows version). This option does not provide any settings. I've also tried the "Equalizer" option, however, there is no setting to clamp all sounds or to set a maximal loudness value (as requested). I can only see a graphic equalizer whose sole purpose is to set the ratios for specific frequencies, if I'm not mistaken. Nonetheless, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ComFreek Ohh, I've Windows 7, may be settings differed a bit, never mind, you welcome :)